# How can I install Gentoo on Virtual Box//(Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: gentoo

I'm googling for a while about how can I install Gentoo on Virtual Box. The hand book provides less information about installing it on virtual box rather on a real partition.

I thought there will be a GUI tool to install Gentoo. [Now I think there is not :(]

Whenever I'm booting into gentoo Im going into a LiveDVD environment where fdisk returning "command not found !" (Not sure this is a bug or Im using a wronng command)

Now Im not a very exprienced user but do like to learn and play with Gentoo. Any help link will be appriciated.

Downloaded File: livedvd-x86-amd64-32ul-2012.iso (Do I need to use Gentoo 64 as OS version in Virtual Box ?)

Comment: I am not sure when the last LiveCD was pusblished, but a normal gentoo install is done through the minimal CD. Check out http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Virtualbox_Guest too

Comment: I already have downloaded a ISO of size 3.4GB. How I can install this on Virtual Box ?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure to install an operating system in Virtual Box is practically identical to installing on real hardware. You still need to partition the virtual disk as if it was a physical one (as described in the Gentoo installation guide) with fdisk (or whatever you prefer). You're best off using the Gentoo minimal CD, but starting from any other Linux environment will also work as long as all the needed tools are available. You might be able to install fdisk (into RAM) with your current live-DVD using the distributions package installation procedure, if it isn't included.

You don't need to install the amd64 version of Gentoo, the x86 version will also work. But note that the amd64 version can provide a hybrid environment also able to run 32bit binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straight forward [blog post](http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/gentoo-x86-linux-installation-on-a-virtualbox-image/) for installing Gentoo on a VirtualBox image for an x86 architecture but it should work for all with slight variation.

Use whichever minimal iso is compatible for your system architecture and download the corresponding portage and stage 3 tarballs.

Comment: Could you summarize the blog post in your reply? Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

We are informed (#gentoo on freenode) that the current amd64 ISO (minimal) has problems. Apparently the ISO from June is currently the best one to use.

It is up to you whether you want 64 or 32 bit guest OS.

Feel free to use this Canadian mirror:
[/releases/amd64/autobuilds/20120621/](http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles/releases/amd64/autobuilds/20120621/)